# Constructor: Storing pre-processed params in helper variables passed to final fields

Tags: dart, constructor

I'd like to provide an alternative constructor for my Circe class where the center and radius are calculated from 3 points. But I cannot find a way to store the calculated center to the temporal variable and pass it to both final fields. Calling _getCenter twice works, but this approach is suboptimal. Is there a more efficient way?

```
import 'dart:math';

class Circle {
  final Point center;
  final double radius;

  Circle(this.center, this.radius);

  Circle.fromPoints(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
      : center = _getCenter(p1, p2, p3),
        radius = _getCenter(p1, p2, p3).distanceTo(p1);

  static Point _getCenter(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of a [factory constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors):

```dart
import 'dart:math';

class Circle {
  final Point center;
  final double radius;

  Circle(this.center, this.radius);

  factory Circle.fromPoints(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    final center = _getCenter(p1, p2, p3);
    final radius = center.distanceTo(p1);

    return Circle(center, radius);
  }

  static Point _getCenter(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The point of such constructor is to behave like a constructor but does not create any object instance automatically. You must then return an object that is compatible with the class the factory constructor is part of.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a `factory` constructor as suggested by [julemand101's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73422090/).  Another approach is to use `late` members so that they can be initialized in a constructor body.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

class Circle {
  late final Point center;
  late final double radius;

  Circle(this.center, this.radius);

  Circle.fromPoints(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    center = _getCenter(p1, p2, p3);
    radius = center.distanceTo(p1);
  }

  static Point _getCenter(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    ...
  }
```

This would matter if you want to use the `fromPoints` constructor from [a redirecting constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#redirecting-constructors) or if you have some derived class that wants to invoke `fromPoints` as a base class constructor.  However, `late` variables are potentially more expensive since they might add runtime checks.